# Change the color of an SVG based on the color of another element?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, colors

I'm in the middle of making a sidebar for a web aplication that uses a user-uploaded image as the background element (seen here: http://c.mhy.me/WwMs). Since the image will be uploaded by the user, I'm wondering if I can change the colour of the logomark on the top (svg) based on the color profile of the image behind it.

For example, if the image has a lot of white, then change the logomark color to a light grey. Otherwise, keep it white for images that are primarily made up of darker colors.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [Background Check](https://github.com/kennethcachia/Background-Check) to identify the lightness of the image directly beneath the logomark and change the colour based on that.